# spring mvc - easiest way to check on what page you are and change style of the menu items

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc, menu

I'm working on a spring mvc project. I need to change the style of my menu items when I'm on a particular page. The css is done. But i still need a way to check on which page I am.

What is the easiest way to do this. All solutions are appreciated.

,
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate **[Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/)** into your Spring MVC project (exmple [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/07/spring-3-mvc-tiles-plugin-tutorial-example-eclipse.html)) and pass path to css needed in `tiles.xml`.

Alternatively you can send this path to your JSP page in **JavaBean**, but it is less declarative and requires accurate manipulating of beans.

Comment: Well I'm using apache tiles, but it is not exactly what I'm searching for. :) I just need to change a css class of a menuItem to '.selected'.

Comment: @user327893: if you have any flag, indicating the page, you can also use JavaScript to get `div` of your menu and change its style. However, I believe, that though tiles is a bit overheading solution for your needs, it will bring you a lot of fun ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this short cut.

Set the style's class name in the ModelAndView as a variable. In the JSP files directly use the variable as the style's class name.

In the controller

```
modelAndView.add("styleVariableName","styleToBeApplied")
```

In the JSP

```
<div class="${styleVariableName}">
```

styleToBeApplied should be a css class and you can repeat this for every controller action.